# Small bar above pagenumber

Tags: header-footer

At the beginning of each chapter, I would like my the pagenumbers to appear like this in the right bottom corner

[image]

which is the standard format used in books published by the American mathematical society. Anyone has a clue how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Is your question just about how to get the bar on top of the page number or about how to put the pagenumber + bar in the bottom right corner? Or how to get the bar+page number only at "the beginning of each chapter" (I'm not sure what this means).  For the latter, it's important to know what document class you are using and what package you are using for setting the headers and footers.  So it would be helpful to add a minimal compilable document that shows this.

Comment: this is *not* the "standard" format used by the american mathematical society; it is a special format used for books in the "graduate studies in mathematics" series.  you can obtain the document class by going to [this page](http://www.ams.org/authors/monopackages) and selecting the author package for that series.  the `gsm-l` document class loads `amsbook`, but then redefines a *lot* of the standard features.  it is nontrivial.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, in the end the "stackengine" package did the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution generated by hacking into the `.cls` file from  [this page](http://www.ams.org/authors/monopackages).

---

```
\documentclass{book}

% Redefine page styles
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
% Used in the chapter start pages
\usepackage{stackengine}
\makeatletter
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\stackanchor{\rule{18\p@}{3\p@}}
    {\thepage}}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.0pt}}
\makeatother
% Used in other pages
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\slshape \leftmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\slshape \rightmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is a Test Chapter}

\section{One Section}

\lipsum[1-20]

\section{Another Section}

\lipsum[21-40]

\chapter{Equation Chapter}
\setcounter{page}{387}

\section{My Equation Will Go in Here}

\lipsum[41-60]



\end{document}
```

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

1. If you want to tweak the page styles further, which I am sure you will, please read the [documentation of fancyhdr](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf).
2. As an alternate, you may want to use directly the .cls file as 
   has been pointed out in the comment from [barbara beeton](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/579/barbara-beeton).
3. My personal advice will be to decide at the very outset, which
   one do you want, changing only the page number style in chapter
   start pages, or complete usage of the `gsm-l` class. Please be warned that, as has been already done in the previously mentioned comment, it "redefines a lot of the standard features. it is nontrivial".